# Уменьшение нагрузки на БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема следующего характера. Есть таблицы: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddb19/14

Мне нужно получить своеобразную ленту вида:

```
%Фамилия имя отчество%
%дата%
%текст%
%количество лайков новости и лайкнул ли я%
  %имя откоментировавшего%
  %дата%
  %текст%
  %количество лайков коментария и лайкнул ли я%
```

Итого выходит (2 + (2x(кол-во новостей+кол-во комментов))) x кол-во пользователей - что много.

**Пожалуйста помогите уменьшить кол-во запросов и увеличить быстродействие. Возможно я неверно подобрал структуру и связи, реструктуризация таблиц возможна.**

Comment: все портят ваши звездочки (news.* и comments.*), а так это два запроса - для новостей и для комментариев. лайки присоединяйте left join'ами и group by по всем полям в выборке...  
ЗЫ сделайте пример на http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddb19/14 вот, там же изложил варианты. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного избыточно, для наглядности:

```
/* Все новости */
select n.id, n.`text`, n.`time`, n.o_uid, u.login, lc.nlikes, lme.ilike
from news n 
  join users u on u.id=n.o_uid
  left join (select count(id) nlikes, nid from likes group by nid) lc on 
    n.id = lc.nid
  left join (select count(id) ilike, nid from likes where o_uid=1 group by nid) lme on
    n.id = lme.nid
;

/* Все комментарии ко всем новостям */
select c.id, c.nid, c.`text`, c.o_uid, u.login, lc.nlikes, lme.ilike
from comments c
  join users u on u.id=c.o_uid
  left join (select count(id) nlikes, cid from likes group by cid) lc on 
    c.id = lc.cid
  left join (select count(id) ilike, cid from likes where o_uid=1 group by cid) lme on
    c.id = lme.cid
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddb19/22)

Comment: да, таблица лайков у вас должна быть своя для комментариев и для новостей, либо комментарий и новости в одной таблице. выигрыша от nid и cid одновременно в likes никакого.

Comment: Спасибо большое, можете пожалуйста пояснить, а то я как-то потерялся в вашем запросе. (откуда взялись псевдонимы для таблиц и т.п.) И как в частности выбрать все комментарии но к определенной новости.

Comment: по поводу псевдонимов все просто:

from comments c

обратите внимание на символы сразу после имени таблицы.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ae96/1 а такой вариант уступает по производительности как-то?

Comment: @GreenBanan по поводу комментарии к определенной новости просто where c.nid=10 добавляете к запросу и все.  
по поводу производительности. тут структура без индексов и данных нет (везде будет full scan), поэтому оба варианты примерно равнозначны... в боевой ситуации надо будет играть и индексами и запросы упрощать или модифицировать.  
Небольшая неоптимальность идет от поля text, которое нельзя вносить в group by, т.к. бесконечно длинные поля в группировке участвовать не могут, а так можно было бы вообще обойтись без вложенных запросов. ну тут оно нужно, поэтому такие запросы тоже нормально.

Comment: Т.е. в принципе мой вариант, тоже подойдет, и значительных огрех в нем нет?

Comment: да, подойдет. Серебряной пули нет (с)...

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли.